# Redirect unauthorised cakePHP users to referrer page

Tags: php, cakephp

Ok, so I have my site set-up in the following way.

The index redirects to the Login page as the entire site is for logged in users only. When a user attempts to view a page they do not have access to they are dumped into the login page with a "You are not authorized to access that location" message.

I want to change this so if a logged in user tried to access a unauthenticated page they get redirected back to the referrer page.

In my individual controllers I have a isAuthorised method that checks the user role and allows or disallows access.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $theme = 'Default';

    public function beforeRender(){
        $this->set('referer',$this->referer());
        $this->set('userData', $this->Auth->user());
    }

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login',
                'home'
            ),
            'authorize' => array('Controller')
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        // Admin can access every action
        if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
            return true;
        }

        // Default deny
        return false;
    }
}
```

Looking through the documentation I have found unauthorizedRedirect and thought this might be able to do it but I've yet to find a way to implement it. I've tried a couple of things but as yet can't find anything that works properly.

Comment: Redirecting back to referrer is already the default behavior if an authenthenticated user tried to access a pages he doesn't have permission to access. What's your CakPHP version?

Comment: Ahh yes, I'm on 2.5. so is my login redirect forcing uses to the login page instead of back to the referrer?

Comment: It would redirect to URL set in `loginRedirect` only if it doesn't find a referrer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in your auth component to redirect the unauthorized users back to the page they came from.

```
'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
```

Looks something like this:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'home'
        ),
        'authorize' => array('Controller'),
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public function beforeRender(){
            $user = READ USER SESSION 
            if(!$this->isAuthorized($user)){
              WRITE REDIRECT CODE HERE
            } 
            $this->set('referer',$this->referer());
            $this->set('userData', $this->Auth->user());
        }
```